# Changing keyboard events with global hook doesn't work

Tags: c#, winapi, hook, native, keyevent

I am trying to make a little program that installs a global hook and catches keyboard input. 
For now, I am trying to make every input changed to 'X' for example.
So if i write anywhere "hello" it will actually write "XXXXX".
I succeeded with hooking and even stopping any input from passing my hook but I can't figure out how to change the input.

The relevant method:

```
IntPtr HookCallBack(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
        // Trying to change the input.
        Marshal.WriteInt32(lParam, 88);

        // Locked down
        if (isKeyboardLockedDown)
            return new IntPtr(1); // A non-zero return value blocks additional processing of key strokes.
        // Not locked down.
        else
            return NativeMethods.CallNextHookEx(hookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);
 }
```

As written above - if I understand right - lParam is the address where the input key is stored.
Therefor I overwrite it with "X".
That method doesn't work for some reason.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If the input is X:

Invoke CallNextHookEx()

Otherwise

Do not invoke CallNextHookEx().  Instead, call SendInput to post an X.

[SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Synthesizes keystrokes, mouse motions, and button clicks.

Note: In general it is unwise not to invoke CallNextHookEx().  Then again, it is in general not wise to replace all input with X :-)

Comment: When the hook procedure gets called, how do you propose to discern between authentic keyboard input, and keyboard input as a result of a call to `SendInput`? The recommendation to drop the call to `CallNextHookEx` is a recipe for disaster: It'll break other code that happens to install a keyboard hook. Always do give other hooks a chance to see the input. There is no requirement to pass the return value of other hooks back, though.

Comment: @IInspectable: In general I would agree with you.  A hook that is replacing all input with X has pretty much already broken the value of other hooks.  Added a mechanism to avoid recursively processing X.  I'm not aware of any mechanism to change the read key before calling the next hook.

Comment: Other hooks may only be interested in the number of keyboard input events, or merely that there was keyboard input at all. The information is still valuable to those hooks, and there's no need to break any more than necessary.

Answer (score -1):

iv'e done a similar project in C. Instead of changing the data i generated input. It works smoothly and not slowing the typing process down.
I used a global flag. True for input i generate and false for input from the user.
This is pretty much how it looked:

```
HookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{  
    if(flag){ 
        flag = FALSE; 
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);}  
    else{ 
        flag = TRUE; 
        keybd_event(what ever you want); 
        return 0;} 
}
```

Comment: This code is based on unfounded assumptions, and happens to work by pure luck. One day you will run out of luck, and there will be another input event in the hardware input queue, when you are faking yours. The result: A false positive followed by a false negative. And two wrongs don't make a right (although three left would, but that is besides the point).

Comment: my code handles only keyboard events... the chance of a keyboard event generated by the user getting in the queue before the HookProc for the previous event finishes is extremely low in my opinion. Any other type of event wouldn't affect the flag and be ignored.

Comment: What about this other app, though, that calls `SendInput` with an array of size greater than 1? Do the odds for failure still sound *"extremely low"* to you? If things can fail, they inevitably will.

Comment: @IInspectable i could learn windows better and make a 100% safe code. Right now the thing i would do is probably set the flag in a better way. the flag is NULL if the input isn't mine, and in a case of generated input the flag is the virtual key code value i sent as input, and i can verify it later.

Comment: and in case `SendInput` generates input that's the same as the input i wanted it's really easy to handle, in case the input is different, it would be ignored.

Comment: The only 100% safe implementation would attach extra information to the message, by calling [SetMessageExtraInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644954.aspx). Since standard keyboard messages belong to the system, that extra information space is also semantically owned by the system, and cannot be used. In essence, there is no guaranteed safe way to discern between input generated by you, and input generated by someone else (hardware device drivers, or other applications calling `SendInput`).